# Issue in a Django's template

Tags: django, listview

Actually, I know it is impossible in a Django's template, but I would like to execute `{{ Perception.objects.filter(loan__request__customer__pk = 207) }}`

Here is the views I use for that template :

```
class PerceptionIndexView(StaffRestrictedMixin, FrontendListView):
    page_title = _('Perception')
    model = Perception
    template_name = 'loanwolf/perception/index.html'
    pjax_template_name = 'loanwolf/perception/index.pjax.html'
    row_actions_template_name = 'loanwolf/perception/list-actions.inc.html'
    url_namespace = 'perception'

    def active(self, obj):
        if obj.is_active:
            return icon(obj.get_icon(), css_class='green-text', tooltip=_('Active'))
        else:
            return icon(obj.get_icon(), css_class='red-text', tooltip=_('Inactive'))

    def notes_count(self, obj):
        return obj.notes.count()
    notes_count_label = _('Notes')

    def get_change_url(self, obj):
        return obj.get_absolute_url()

    def my_view(self, A_pk):
        filter_perceptions= Perception.objects.filter(loan__request__customer__pk=A_pk)
        return render_to_response('../template/loanwolf/perception/list-view-#2.inc.html', {'filter_perceptions': filter_perceptions})
```

I tried to use `render_to_response` with different path, but nothing happen so far. knowing that my view is located in `loanwolf/perception` and my template `list-view-#2.inc.html` is located in `loanwolf/templates/loanwolf/perception`. Furthermore, it is important to know that FrontendListView use a ListView. I think I could not use a 'render_to_response', but it is unclear.

Could anyone have an alternative solution so that I could access the list `Perception.objects.filter(loan__request__customer__pk)` in my template?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Put the code that is inside your `my_view` into a method called `get_context_data`, similar to this:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(PerceiptionIndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    filter_perceptions = Perception.objects.filter(loan__request__customer__pk=...)
    context["filter_perceptions"] = filter_perceptions
    return context
```

Then `filter_perceptions` will be available in your template via `{{filter_perceptions}}`

Look at the docs for more examples if you need something slightly different.

Comment: I know well this method, but it was unclear for me how to do such thing. Question : I could access the pk of a customer with `{{ customer.pk }}`. By what could I replace `...` from you answer? Knowing that `customer` is an object from the context of that template.

Comment: What do you want the customer to be? If for example it's the current logged in user, you can use self.request.user. You can access other arguments with self.kwargs.

Comment: Nice try, but I can't use your whole answer, because `self` is `<loanwolf.customers.views.CustomerPerceptionIndexView object at 0x7fe76ed02fd0>`

Comment: Yes, that's what self is. It should still contain those variables.